# How to retrieve Firebase ID Token from Spring Backend

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, jwt

I am working on Spring Boot Rest Backend where I Used Firebase JWT ID Token for authentication. where for better security Client side should have to send valid ID Token( for each n every Rest call ) which get them from firebase by passing username n password to firebase.

Everything works fine but now i have scenario where i have to make bakend call to some another server where Above Security also implemented.

For client side, Firebase already have some Classes and well documentation for retrieve Firebase ID token from Front End and send towards sever for verification but **didn't get any solution for How to retrieve  Firebase ID Token from Spring Backend for communicating with another server.**!

I can also save client token in middle ware and used this for my own server request but this look not fine for me.

Need some suggestion on How to retrieve  Firebase ID Token from Spring Backend for communicating with another server.!

Comment: Hello , did you implement this in different ways ?